# Where the power series is convergent

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Where $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^n}{n}z^n$ is convergent?

I checked that the radius of convergence is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, since we know that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}z^n$ is convergent on a unit ball except for point $1$ (it is a well-known fact), we check when $(2i)^n \cdot z^n=1$. The only point lying on $|z|=1/2$ that satisfies that equation is $z=-\frac{i}{2}$.

So we conclude that $f(z)$ is convergent in $\overline{B}(0,\frac{1}{2})\setminus\{-\frac{i}{2}\}$

Is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;z=-\frac i2\;$ then sequence's general term is

$$\frac{(2i)^n}{n}\left(-\frac i2\right)^n=(-1)^n\frac{i^{2n}}n=(-1)^n\frac{(-1)^n}n=\frac1n$$

and the series indeed diverges, so yes: it looks your work is fine.

Comment: If the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}z^n$ convergence on unit ball except for $1$ was well know on our classes(we proved it during classes - using Dirichlet test- and our professor told us that we can use this fact later) do you think that my answer is ok? Or should I write sth more?

Comment: I think is fine, @luka5z. I was trying another way but got stuck. Perhaps later I shall come back to this.

Comment: Here you have general proof i you would like to take a look: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/dirichlet.pdf

Comment: And thank you for your help!

Comment: @luka5z My pleasure and thank you.